# Getting contents from useStyles()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whilte creating different props with `useStyles()` they can be accessed in elemens like

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    title: {
        margin: theme.spacing(4, 0, 2)
    }
)

return (
    <Typography className={classes.title}>text</Typography>
)
```

However if I try to log the contents it returns me a string `makeStyles-title-7`

```
function App() {
    const classes = useStyles()
    console.log(classes.title)
```

How to access the contents stored within? How to log them properly?

Answer (score 1):

Material-ui uses [CSS-in-JS](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/a-journey-toward-better-style) solution to write component styles.This helps to achieve modularity and describe styles in a declarative, conflict-free and reusable way.

The class names are generated automatiaclly such that they are unique in nature and do not conflicts with global CSS names.Thats why when you do

```
console.log(classes.title)
```

it prints values like `makeStyles-title-7`

Styles definition will be injected at runtime in `<head>` element.(You can change this behaviour as well)

[image]

You can learn more about JSS and various configurable options from here - https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.1.1